# Proper NFD form of emoji and comparison

Tags: unicode, nfd

Given that there is now a selector for textual vs emoji display for some codepoints, what is the proper decomposed form of those codepoints? For instance, ❤︎ (U+2764) defaults to a text representation, but can become an emoji if followed by VS-16 (U+fe0f): ❤️. You can force a text representation with VS-15 (U+fe0e).  Does this mean the NFD for U+2764 should become U+2764 U+fe0e?  Should U+2764 U+fe0e and U+2764 be treated as the same (in the same way é (U+00e9) is the same as é (U+0065 U+0301))? What about the text vs emoji representations?  Should they be treated the same as well?

Comment: Interesting, ❤︎ (U+2764) in this question shows up as emoji on Android, but as text on OS X in chrome. I wonder what ❤︎ (U+2764 U+fe0e) will do. Still emoji, so that is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

There's no [decomposition mapping](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Character_Decomposition_Mappings) in the [Unicode database](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) for emojis and variation selectors. The standard [even states](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch23.pdf):

> The initial character in a variation sequence is never [...] a canonical decomposable character.

This means that emojis with or without variation selector don't change under NFD.

Also, to my knowledge, Unicode doesn't specify the default representation of a code point without variation selector. This is up to the implementation.